# GPUImageExposureFilter switches image dimensions?

Tags: ios, xcode, gpuimage

I am running GPUImageExposureFilter on some images. When I do this on a portrait image, for some reason it resizes the aspect ratio of the image to landscape.

The images change from 2448 x 3264 to 3264 x 2448 when I run this filter. I'm trying to track down the issue. If you recognize the issue, any help would be much appreciated.

Filter setup

```
GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *exposureFilter;
exposureFilter = [[GPUImageExposureFilter alloc] init];
```

slider:

```
[(GPUImageExposureFilter *)exposureFilter setExposure:[exposureSlider value]];
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a possible framework bug. Could you post the code that you use to set up this filter chain as an issue on the GitHub issues page: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues ?